# Adding methods (roles) to a class on the fly in Python - dangers?

Tags: python, traits, roles

I'm learning python, and having fun with classes. Since I'm used to [roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-oriented_programming) or [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) in other contexts and found them extremely useful, I was looking into the same kind of thing - adding a class to another class' inheritance chain. Like this:

```
class A():
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')


class B():
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')


a = A()
b = B()

a.foo()
b.bar()

class C(A, B):
    pass


class Z():
    def baz(self):
        print('baz')

C = type("C", (C, Z), {})

c = C()

c.foo()
c.bar()
c.baz()
```

where in real life `C` will probably have been defined elsewhere, and not necessarily by me.

Seems too smooth to be true: any hidden dangers I might not be aware of? Obviously: redefining existing methods - but anything else?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand what you are asking. This is jsut inheritance AFAIKT. You create *two* distinct classes named "C" here... not sure why you didn't just do `class C(C, Z): pass`. Or perhaps more reasonably, `class D(C, Z): pass`

Comment: You are redefining `C`, not adding methods on the fly. Check `id(C)` before and after your change to compare. Adding new methods would be monkey-patching, i.e. `C.baz = lambda self: print('baz')`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - why _two_ distinct classes? does the "old" ```C``` class still exist? as to why - as I said in question: I do not "own" the original class C, I keep 100% of its behaviour, and I just want to add a few traits (see links).

Comment: @Selcuk - so redifining as "do everything that C used to do and these things on top" - right? And thanks for the ``ìd(C)``` hint - that's the type of stuff that you can't find by googling

Comment: The "old" `C` still exists but inaccessible. You could have done something like `OldC = C` before the `type` trick and it would be accessible as `OldC`. And yes, you are extending `C` while still confusingly naming the subclass `C`, so it's not different than what @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned (i.e. `class C(C, Z): pass`).

Comment: @simone yes, of *course* it still exists, *you are inheriting from it*. All you've done here is normal inheritance, it is **exactly** the same as `class D(C, Z): pass` (using `D` as a name to emphasize that you have a totally distinct class).

Comment: @Selcuk - got it now, thanks. Why is that before doing ```C = type("C", (C, Z), {})``` I would insert checks (such as method redefines and probably more). Also - it may well be because with about 40 days of python behind me I could be totally wrong

Comment: @Selcuk it's not inaccessible.  You can retrieve it like so: `OldC = C.mro()[1]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - inheritance is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Please do take a look at the links I put at the top of the question. They do a better job at explaining why I might find this desirable

Comment: @simone but *you haven't avoided inheritance at all*. You are 100% using inheritance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - so no dangers, apart from the ones I mentioned? "is it dangerous" is what I'm asking in the question, sorry if I am being narrowly focused

Comment: @simone well, it's dangerous if you *dont' understand what you are doing*. See my answer for an example of unexpected behavior in your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just normal inheritance. You seem to be misinterpreting this because you are naming the subclass the same as one of its base classes, i.e. `C`.

But

```
C = type("C", (C, Z), {})
```

Is just the same as:

```
class C(C, Z):
    pass
```

Note, very importantly, if there exists an instance of the original C:

```
>>> class A():
...     def foo(self):
...         print('foo')
...
>>>
>>> class B():
...     def bar(self):
...         print('bar')
...
>>> class C(A, B):
...     pass
...
>>> old_c_instance = C()
```

It will not be considered an instance of the new C:

```
>>> class Z():
...     def baz(self):
...         print('baz')
...
>>> C = type("C", (C, Z), {})
>>> isinstance(old_c_instance, C)
False
```

Note, the old C can be recovered, it will be the second class in the method resolution order (the first of the base):

```
>>> OldC = C.mro()[1]
>>> OldC
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> C
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> isinstance(old_c_instance, OldC)
True
```

So this is just an example of a confusingly named subclass.

Note, the pattern here is the "Mixin pattern". As noted in the wiki-link, traits are basically like mixins, but they generally don't carry instance state. Well, you can just *omit* that from your mixin and now you basically have a trait... using inheritance.

Note, you *can* actually add methods on the fly in Python:

```
class A():
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

class B():
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

class C(A, B):
    pass
```

Then, something like:

```
def baz(self):
    print('baz')

def qux(self):
    print('qux')

for func in [baz, qux]:
    setattr(C, func.__name__, func)

C().baz()
C().qux()
```

This avoids inheritance and the creation of a new class. A lot of metaprogramming is very mundane in Python.